# GridControl Master - Detail view with a stored procedure

Tags: c#, winforms, stored-procedures, devexpress, gridcontrol

My first stored procedure looks like this:

```
Use [Stock]
Go
Create Proc Get_Orders
AS
SELECT [Number_Order]
  ,[Date_Order]
  ,[FullName]
  ,[Location]
FROM [Order]
```

and my second stored procedure looks like this:

```
USE [Stock]
GO
ALTER Proc [dbo].[Get_Order_Res]
AS

SELECT i.Name_Item
  ,od.[ID_Order]
  ,od.[Project]
  ,od.[Length]
  ,od.[Width]
  ,od.[Quantity]
  ,od.[Weight]
  ,od.[Supplier]
  ,od.[GDS_Name]
  ,od.[GDS_Date]
  ,od.[WorkshopName]
  ,od.[WorkshopDate]
  ,od.[ReservedQty]
 FROM OdredDetails od
   INNER JOIN ItemQuantity iq 
           ON iq.ID_ItemQte = od.ID_ItemQte 
   INNER JOIN item i
           ON i.ID_Item = iq.ID_Item 
   INNER JOIN [Order] ord
           ON ord.Number_Order=od.ID_Order
 where ord.[Location]='PRODUCTION'
```

in my c# code, I use this code to get data from a stored procedure

```
        public DataTable Get_Order_Res()
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DAL.SelectData("Get_Order_Res", null);
        DAL.Close();
        return dt;

    }
    public DataTable Get_Orders()
    {
        DAL.DataAccessLayer DAL = new DAL.DataAccessLayer();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt = DAL.SelectData("Get_Orders", null);
        DAL.Close();
        return dt;

    }
```

and in my form i use this code to create master detail view

```
    public partial class FRM_Reserved : Form
{
BL.CLS_Order ord = new BL.CLS_Order();
DataTable master = new DataTable();
DataTable details = new DataTable();
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
public FRM_Reserved()
 {
InitializeComponent();      
master = ord.Get_Orders();
details = ord.Get_Order_Res();
dataSet.Tables.Add(master);
dataSet.Tables.Add(details);
dataSet.Relations.Add("OderDetails",
dataSet.Tables["master"].Columns["Number_Order"],
dataSet.Tables["details"].Columns["ID_Order"]);
gridControl3.DataSource = dataSet.Tables["master"];
```

but when i run the code i get error:Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[image]
help me please,thanks in advance.

Comment: So you need to debug and check which line throws the error and fix it.

Comment: yes i tried and i found that the problem was in dataSet.Relations.Add but i cannot find how to fix it.i also check if the stored procedure return data                                                                                                             gridControl3.DataSource =ord.Get_Orders();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you havent given names to your data tables, hence when you are trying to access them then it returns null.

```
dataSet.Tables["master"] // this returns null
```

To fix this, give names to your data tables

```
DataTable master = new DataTable("master");
DataTable details = new DataTable("details");
```

Comment: I change it, but still the same problem.

Comment: Check if after this line, master = ord.Get_Orders(); do you have the data table name set?

Comment: for master i get Table1 and for details i get Table2

Comment: then use them as dataSet.Tables["Table1"] or update their names

Comment: i change it ,and it work .thanks Shivani Katukota i am very grateful